# What are the major results of ISS experiments?

Tags: iss

For about 15 years the astronauts are doing scientific research in the ISS for future space population and traveling.The wide variety of research fields include astrobiology, astronomy, human research including space medicine and life sciences, physical sciences, materials science, space weather, and weather on Earth. But what till now are the most remarkable results of this?

Perhaps one important example of each field can be mentioned?

Comment: Please [edit] to define what you'd consider as the most remarkable.

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask a broad question, you get a broad answer. All the publications and results of experiments run on the ISS to date are available [here](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/Publications.html).

UPDATE: A shorter list of highlights and Utilisation Reports up to August 2014 are [here](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/research_library_rev1_no_proposals2014(7).pdf) from this [site](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/overview.html).

Happy Hunting!

Comment: In case you're wondering, that's about 1000 papers.

Comment: @Hobbes, maybe more. There may be annual activity reports amongst them.

Answer (score 3):

In 2013 ISS chief scientist Julie Robinson listed the Top 10 ISS Research Results.  So in the project's own assessment, these were the most important as of 2013. They are linked [here](http://spaceksc.blogspot.com/2013/11/the-iss-top-ten.html) so I won't copy the links but here are the subjects.

I find this list kind of disappointing (especially # 4 which isn't a research result at all) but perhaps great progress has been made since 2013!

1. New Targeted Method of Chemotherapy Drug Delivery; Clinical Breast Cancer Trials Now in Development
2. Robotic Assist for Brain Surgery
3. Dark Matter is Still Out There
4. 43 Million Students and Counting
5. Pathway for Bacterial Pathogens to Become Virulent
6. New Process of “Cool Flame” Combustion
7. Colloid Self Assembly Using Electrical Fields for Nanomaterials
8. Hyperspectral Imaging for Water Quality in Coastal Bays
9. Understanding Mechanisms of Osteoporosis and New Drug Treatments
10. Preventing Loss of Bone Mass in Space Through Diet and Exercise

Comment: But where are the new drugs for treatment of osteoporosis, can I buy them at a pharmacy?